# ACL vs standard file permissions - which are used when accessing file?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

ACLs and standard file permissions seem to be synchronized:

```
$ getfacl test.cpp
# file: test.cpp
# owner: scdmb
# group: scdmb
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--

$ ls -l test.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 2 scdmb scdmb 173 Jan  1  1970 test.cpp
```

However as I've read there are two locations in inode to save file permissions (i_mode field) and these extended file attributes where ACLs are placed. So when I access file then which file permissions are used - standard or ACLs? Or maybe this is the same thing presented in different ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `getfacl` [manpage](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/getfacl1.html):

> The output format of getfacl is as follows:

```
           1:  # file: somedir/
           2:  # owner: lisa
           3:  # group: staff
           4:  user::rwx
           5:  user:joe:rwx               #effective:r-x
           6:  group::rwx                 #effective:r-x
           7:  group:cool:r-x
           8:  mask:r-x
           9:  other:r-x
          10:  default:user::rwx
          11:  default:user:joe:rwx       #effective:r-x
          12:  default:group::r-x
          13:  default:mask:r-x
          14:  default:other:---
```

> Lines 4, 6 and 9 correspond to the user, group and other fields of  the
>          file mode permission bits. These three are called the base ACL entries.
>          Lines 5 and 7 are named user and named group entries.  Line  8  is  the
>          effective  rights  mask. This entry limits the effective rights granted
>          to all groups and to named users. (The file owner  and  others  permis-
>          sions  are not affected by the effective rights mask; all other entries
>          are.)  Lines 10--14 display the default ACL associated with this direc-
>          tory.  Directories  may  have a default ACL. Regular files never have a
>          default ACL.

The fact that yours shows lines only with `::` and not `<user|group|other>:<name>:<perms>` indicates that **you have no** extended ACLs. For this particular file, you are just using `getfacl` as a fancy way of obtaining the same info as would show in `ls -la` (the user/group/other permission bits aka the "base ACL".)

As for which permissions are **used**: the short answer is it depends on the *order* of the ACLs. See [here](https://www.cs.unc.edu/cms/help/help-articles/posix-acls-in-linux) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) for details. In general, if a deny comes first in the ACL list, it is impossible to later on give the permission back with an explicit allow. Denies always take precedence.

There's an even longer article with more references [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92414/22703) on Unix.SE.