# How can I share a GNOME Boxes VM with another user account?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, gnome

I am using GNOME Boxes on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10. I have a Windows 7 Virtual machine. I would like to have both of my users have access to the VM. The user which the VM was created on is an "Administrator", and the other users are "Standard".

How is it possible for me to share the VM with other users on the same computer?

Answer (score 0):

On linux you have 2 ways to accomplish this: file permissions and ACL.

Check [this](https://superuser.com/a/745699/168706) post for an explanation.

For file permissions, you just need to add both users to the same group and assign to that group read write permissions on the file.

For ACL, check on google on how to do it. A simple example is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists#Examples)

I don't know exactly what are you trying to say with "the user is an administrator".

So, for username1=Administrator, username2=Standard and the path to the file being /path/to/probably/kvm/image.img you need to do the following as root:

```
groupadd windows_image
usermod -a -G windows_image Administrator
usermod -a -G windows_image Standard
chgrp -R windows_image /path/to/probably/kvm/image.img
chmod -R 770 //path/to/probably/kvm/image.img
```

Off course, you need to know where your windows image is.